# Know dimensions of vectors stored in a for loop

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes contained in a for loop line.

The for loop looks like this:

```
 for (i in 2:ncol(raw_df)) assign(paste0("id_", names(raw_df)[i]), raw_df[ ,c(1:i)])
```

There are 50 vectors inside this `for` loop. In each vector, there are two columns ("id" and "traitX") and variable number of rows. How do I know the dimensions of each dataframe in just one run?

Comment: You are generating these objects in a very ugly, awkward way. Perhaps provide some more information on your real goal here? Why do you want to generate these 50 data.frame objects? (Also this line is generating data.frames, not vectors, and they are going to have more than 2 columns. A vector will never have 2 columns)

Comment: Sorry for incorrect usage. Yes, I meant dataframes. I want to do this just to check the number of individuals showing significant values for each of the different traits, because prior to this I did some filtrations. After I've known the number of individuals (dimensions ie. the row number), I will proceed to another process which is inner-joining the list of individuals with another set of dataframe for each trait.

Comment: Why don't you do this in the raw data.frame (`raw_df`)? instead of breaking it out into separate frames. I'd suggest taking a look at `dplyr` tutorials.

Comment: No, raw_df has different number of rows for each column trait.

Comment: Then it is not a data.frame. It is a list and `ncol` is going to be returning `NULL`. If you built a data.frame using objects of different lengths R will either give an error or repeat them. (See `data.frame(A=1:3,B=1:4)` and `data.frame(A=1:2,B=1:4)` as examples.)